# express js internal server error 500 with no errors in code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, blockchain

my express js routes are giving me error 500 internal server error and I tried to console log the variables and nothing shows up

here are the express routes:

```
submitStar() {
        this.app.post("/submitstar", async (req, res) => {
            if(req.body.address && req.body.message && req.body.signature && req.body.star) {
                const address = req.body.address;
                const message = req.body.message;
                const signature = req.body.signature;
                const star = req.body.star;
                try {
                    let block = await this.blockchain.submitStar(address, message, signature, star);
                    if(block){
                        return res.status(200).json(block);
                    } else {
                        return res.status(500).send("An error happened!");
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    return res.status(500).send(error);
                }
            } else {
                return res.status(500).send("Check the Body Parameter!");
            }
        });
    }
```

I keep getting the message "Check the Body Parameter!" in Postman while the message is actually correct

[image]

the app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

   
/**
 * Require the Blockchain class. This allow us to have only one instance of the class.
 */
const BlockChain = require('./src/blockchain.js');

class ApplicationServer {

    constructor() {
        //Express application object
        this.app = express();
        //Blockchain class object
        this.blockchain = new BlockChain.Blockchain();
        //Method that initialized the express framework.
        this.initExpress();
        //Method that initialized middleware modules
        this.initExpressMiddleWare();
        //Method that initialized the controllers where you defined the endpoints
        this.initControllers();
        //Method that run the express application.
        this.start();
    }

    initExpress() {
        this.app.set("port", 8000);
    }

    initExpressMiddleWare() {
        this.app.use(morgan("dev"));
        this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
        this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
    }

    initControllers() {
        require("./BlockchainController.js")(this.app, this.blockchain);
    }

    start() {
        let self = this;
        this.app.listen(this.app.get("port"), () => {
            console.log(`Server Listening for port: ${self.app.get("port")}`);
        });
    }

}

new ApplicationServer();
```

what could be wrong with server?

Comment: Do req.body contains the keys you mentioned? If it is not you may have to use body parser to convert to json object.

Comment: I tried to console.log(req.body) but nothing showed up in the terminal

Comment: Please check the app.js file for body parser package

Comment: Replace with your router variable in the above. It may be like
const router = express.Router(); 
Refer this link https://github.com/sujithmp/nodejs-auth-system-back-end-1/blob/master/app.js

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes in the code.

```
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");


/**
  * Require the Blockchain class. This allow us to have only one instance of 
  * the class.
*/
const BlockChain = require('./src/blockchain.js');

class ApplicationServer {

   constructor() {
    //Express application object
    this.app = express();
    //Blockchain class object
    this.blockchain = new BlockChain.Blockchain();
    //Method that initialized the express framework.
    this.initExpress();
    //Method that initialized middleware modules
    this.initExpressMiddleWare();
    //Method that initialized the controllers where you defined the endpoints
    this.initControllers();
    //Method that run the express application.
    this.start();
   }

   initExpress() {
     this.app.set("port", 8000);
   }

   initExpressMiddleWare() {
    this.app.use(morgan("dev"));
    this.router = express.Router();
    this.router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
    this.router.use(bodyParser.json());
   }

   initControllers() {
      require("./BlockchainController.js")(this.app, this.blockchain);
      // console.log(this.app.route(),"this.app")
   }

   start() {
    let self = this;
    
    this.router.post('/',(req,res) => {
        console.log(req.body.id,"body");
        res.status(200).send('Hello');
    })
    this.app.use(this.router);
    this.app.listen(this.app.get("port"), (req,res) => {
        console.log(`Server Listening for port: ${self.app.get("port")}`);
    });
   }

 }

 new ApplicationServer();
```

Comment: it's giving me "router" is undefined

Comment: Refer this link https://github.com/sujithmp/nodejs-auth-system-back-end-1/blob/master/app.js

Comment: I implemented that and it didn't help, and also there are other routes were working without it too

Comment: Where is your route? You need to use body parser with router

Comment: actually I don't think the server needs body parser because other requests are working fine without it

Comment: this.app.Router().use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
this.app.Router().use(bodyParser.json());
Add these two line in your initExpressMiddleWare() method

Comment: it's giving error: TypeError: this.app.Router is not a function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230376/discussion-between-astrosixer-and-mai-mohamed).